# How can I transform posted XML to a POCO in an MVC action?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following method signature for an action on an MVC controller:

```
public ActionResult DoSomething(int id, string anotherParameter, IEnumerable<StronglyTypedThing> data)
{
}
```

This method is called by an AJAX Request (in this instance I'm using ExtJS, but that should have little/no bearing on this I imagine!) which passes up, for example:

```
id: 1,
anotherParameter: 'cake',
data: '<stronglyTypedThings>
          <stronglyTypedThing>
            <id>1</id>
            <anotherProperty>Smith, John></anotherProperty>
          </stronglyTypedThing>
          <stronglyTypedThing>
            <id>2</id>
            <anotherProperty>Doe, Jane></anotherProperty>
          </stronglyTypedThing>
        </stronglyTypedThings>'
```

Currently the method signature I've shown above is *not* what I have, instead the final parameter is defined as `string data` and I have what is effectively boilerplate code which transforms the XML string into an `IEnumerable<StronglyTypedThing>`.

Is there a way to have (either by virtue of something baked into MVC, or by extending it) MVC deal with the grunt-work for me so I don't have the boilerplate code present in my action method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom model binder.
This link will have an example of custom xml binder: http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2011/06/24/model-binding-xml-in-asp-net-mvc-3/

Comment: A custom model binder appears to apply to the entire request, rather than one specific element of it. To be clear, I'm looking for a way to automatically transform *one of many* elements (that's been passed in as XML) of the request into a POCO

Comment: Turns out you can apply a custom model binder to a specific parameter to an action, so that's what I did and it worked like a treat, thank you (albeit belatedly! =)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into a custom `ValueProviderFactory`.

A custom `XmlValueProviderFactory` will parse the incoming xml string and construct an intermediate dictionary. (which MVC uses to model bind)

Based on your need, you could parse the whole XML/or a part of it, to construct the dictionary equivalent of your Model object. Once there, MVC will take care of creating the Model for you using Model Binding. Also, value providers have the additional benefit of input validation which custom model binders don't have.

Please see following help links to see a JSON & XML Value Provider factory.
i think the JSON Value provider is now in built, but not the XML one. not sure.

http://haacked.com/archive/2010/04/15/sending-json-to-an-asp-net-mvc-action-method-argument.aspx/
http://www.nogginbox.co.uk/Media/files/XmlValueProviderFactory.txt